# HTML text being printed as plain text using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Following is a small snippet that prints a chunk of text that includes some html tags as well like `<strong></strong>`:

```
{% if doc.highlight %}
    {% for entry in doc.highlight.text %}
        {{entry}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

`{{entry}}` is the variable that has the chunk of text like `finds the optimum (least rate) uniquely <strong>decodable</strong>, variable length entropy`. This will print the text with the HTML tags also!!

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

[Because Jinja2 will auto escape HTML tags](https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html#html-escaping), to disable it, try:

```
{% if doc.highlight %}
    {% for entry in doc.highlight.text %}
        {{ entry|safe }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The [safe filter](https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html#safe)

> [marks] the value as safe which means that in an environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be escaped.

Comment: Well thanks, that did the job. What are those `|safe` called?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey I've just add a link of the document :)

Comment: `|safe` overwrites the built-in XSS defenses. Use it wisely.

Comment: As @RickViscomi said, text  with `|safe` can use all of the HTML tags, for example, `<script>`. So  only use `|safe` if you really trust the text.